# What is the difference between local and json logging drivers?

Tags: docker, logging

Both, JSON and local logging drivers, seem to store logs per container, locally.

In JSON driver docs, I see the extra options of labels and env (because JSON can have attributes?). Also, local driver documentation says that it uses "internal storage". But I could not find what the fundamental difference is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/):

- local    Logs are stored in a custom format designed for minimal
  overhead.
- json-file    The logs are formatted as JSON. The default
  logging driver for Docker.

Explanation:

- local => log saved as it is written.
- json-file => formatted to:

```json
{
     "log":"log message",
     "stream":"stdout",
     "time":"2019-10-12T12:44:45.931849055Z"
}
```